# How to match parent AnchorPane to HBox in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, anchor, pane, hbox

I am using `JavaFX` and I have `HBox` parent and `AnchorPane` child, so when I resize the parent, the child doesn't resize, I wanna make the AnchorPane fill the parent (like `match_parent` in android).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set HGrow = ALWAYS in the AnchorPane.

```
<AnchorPane maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
```

Comment: I think it is also important to read the javadoc for [`HBox`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/HBox.html) to understand what is actually going on here.  If you only have a single item in your HBox, a StackPane may be a more appropriate container (in which case you also wouldn't need the additional sizing hint).  For the `HGrow`, when you have multiple items in the HBox (which you normally would), the sizing hint will set the priority for which nodes grow to fill available space, even with HGrow set to always, other items will take up their min space or more.